# Automatically get License Information of all dependent open source artifacts in a commercial project

Tags: java, maven, open-source

In our company there are many JEE backend applications which are deployed to jfrog artifactory. Each of this projects contains some dependency to other maven repository sources, which in turn have a lot of other dependencies. So when I use one of the dependencies, like

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>          
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Sample.ProjectA.Project-A could have some commercial dependencies. 
I see that maven uses the licenses field to put license info

```
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
```

I also found a way to get the maven licenses with the reports info plugin [maven-project-info-reports-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/)

Now it would be great, to tell maven to warn if there are any commercial licenses. Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of Maven plugins that verify the licenses used by a project's dependencies:

- "ayoy-license-verifier-maven-plugin" ([reference](https://www.ayoy.se/en/blog/2017/10-27-maven-license-plugin/))
- "khmarbaise/Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin" ([reference](http://khmarbaise/Maven-License-Verifier-Plugin))

However, there are problems with this approach:

- Some Maven artifacts do not declare a license in their POM files.
- These plugins rely on the `<license>` in a dependency's POM using *well known* names or URLs for the licenses.  Unfortunately, these are not standardized (as illustrated in the example "licenses.xml" files).  It is up to you to figure out a way to deal with this.
- These plugins do not attempt to classify licenses as "commercial" or "non-commercial".  You have to work that out for yourself.

Comment: You can simply get a list of used licenses via https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/download-licenses-mojo.html

Comment: Is there a way to get this via Artifactory Rest API if I am using Artifactory to store all builds and dependencies?

Comment: @Lovey - That is a different question.  Do some research, and if you don't find any answers, ask a new question.  (I suspect that it won't be possible because it strikes me that Artifactory would not have the information needed to work it out.  For example, it doesn't necessarily have the details of all of your project's remote repos.)

Comment: @StephenC: Actually Artifactory does have API to find license for your dependency. Only question is to find all dependencies of my build/artifact (once I upload the final artifact to artifactory). Will post here once I find a solution.

Comment: I think that the API method you are thinking of is querying the licenses of the artifacts published in your Artifactory repo.  Not the licenses of their (transitive) dependencies.